# mysql insert max + 1 error

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a win form that contain a data grid, i add rows to it and i want to insert this row in the database but each row has its own ID so i wrote this query and try do do this but with errors especially when try to insert max ID +1 in each row please help me to write this query correctly.

Here is my query:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    OracleConnection CN = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
    string Query = 
           "insert into EMP_HASM_DET " +
           "(MAXID,EMPID,GHYAB,TAGMEE3,GZA) " +
           "  (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(MAXID) FROM EMP_HASM_DET)), 1),'" + 
           this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "','" + 
           this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + 
           this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + 
           this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "'";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Query, CN);
    CN.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CN.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: i have this error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: When you debug it, what is your `Query` string exactly when you pass it's line?

Comment: that is my exact query and i enter values in data grid cell and that is also my             ConnectionString = "Data Source=business;Persist Security Info=True;Password=ab4net;User ID=employees_net";

Comment: Not your connection string, your `Query` string which include your sql statement.

Comment: @user2746526 not sure but it is possible that you forgot to write values. Could you try like that : insert into EMP_HASM_DET (MAXID,EMPID,GHYAB,TAGMEE3,GZA) values ( (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(MAXID) FROM EMP_HASM_DET)), 1)) ... But do not forget to open extra paranthesis after values and close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts...

- I don't see a VALUES clause in your sql, I think that may be part of the problem.
- You tagged the question as MySQL but you reference an Oracle connection in your code sample... which is it?
- You are opening and closing your connection for every row.  That's a lot of overhead, open it once, issue your commands, then close it.

Although not directly related to your question, you might consider reformatting your code to use String.Format as shown below.  It makes things a little easier to read.  Particularly because you aren't constantly appending single-quotes.  Put a Debug.WriteLine statement in your code like I have and let us know what it outputs... that might make your problem much more obvious and allow us to help you better.

-- Untested code follows --

```
string sqlTemplate = "INSERT INTO EMP_HASM_DET(MAXID,EMPID,GHYAB,TAGMEE3,GZA) VALUES ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')";
string sqlSubquery = "(SELECT COALESCE(max(MAXID)+1, 1) FROM EMP_HASM_DET)";

OracleConnection CN = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
CN.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  string Query = String.Format(sqlTemplate, 
        sqlSubquery,
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value,
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value,
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value,
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

  Debug.WriteLine(Query);

  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Query, CN);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
CN.Close();
```

Comment: Ok, still do the debug.writeline so we can see exactly the final query that is being pushed.